# React - событие onChange таблицы Antd дает предыдущее значение

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я делаю парсинг из таблицы [Antd](https://ant.design/components/table/) в React. И моя проблема в том, что эти данные я получаю с предыдущими значениями таблицы (т.е. на событии таблицы onChange. Мне нужен совет, как получить фактические(текущие) данные из таблицы.

OnChange:

```
let onChange = (pagination, filters, sorter, extra) => {
        set_filters(filters);xlsxFileHandler();
    }
```

Обработчик:

```
let xlsxFileHandler =() => {
if (dataSource) {
    table = document.querySelectorAll("table");
    table1=table[0];
    table2=table[1];
    output = document.querySelector("pre");
    setMyData( parseTable(table1,table2));  
}
}
```

Я думаю, одна из идей - использовать стрелочную функцию, но как это сделать? Другая идея - найти другое событие таблицы, которое я могу использовать. Есть идеи?

Upd. То же самое, например, происходит в React, когда у меня есть, скажем, обработчик Button с несколькими инструкциями внутри - кнопку нужно нажать дважды, чтобы получить ожидаемые результаты. Или datepicker - он дает мне предыдущее значение даты при использовании его события onChange.

Upd1. Уже потерялся код кнопки, до этого было. Но есть от календаря:

```
let f1GetStartDate =(date) => {
date1=date.toISOString().slice(0,10);
console.log("Start "+date1);
if (date2) {
interval=`<= date'${date2.toString()}' + interval '1 day' and timestamp>=date'${date1.toString()}'`;
}
}

let f1GetEndDate =(date) => {
date2=date.toISOString().slice(0,10);
console.log("End "+date2);
if (date1) {
interval=`<= date'${date2.toString()}' + interval '1 day' and timestamp>=date'${date1.toString()}'`;
}
}

<p><DatePicker
       selected={startDate}
       selectsStart
       startDate={startDate}
       onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
       onSelect={f1GetStartDate}
       locale={ru}
       dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
       shouldCloseOnSelect={true}

     /></p>
     <p><DatePicker
       selected={endDate}
       selectsEnd
       endDate={endDate}
       minDate={startDate}
       onChange={date => setEndDate(date)}
       onSelect={f1GetEndDate}
       locale={ru}
       dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
       shouldCloseOnSelect={true}
```

Из-за того что я не мог получить текущую(выбранную мышкой) дату с onChange, то придумал использовать onSelect. А в таблице похожой уловки нет. Тогда как раз была эта кнопка, она обрабатывала запрос с бд с интервалом. И туда уходило предыдущее значение даты. А текущий обработчик кнопки:

```
let  btnHandler = () => {
      if (date1 && date2) {
      refetchAll(events.options.all.variables);console.log("win-win");
      console.log(date1,date2);
}}

<p><Button onClick={btnHandler}>Поиск</Button></p>
```

Comment: Можете добавить пример кода с кнопкой, что необходимо кликнуть дважды?

Comment: Добавил пример. Также этот топик на анг. есть с большим кодом - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66240171/react-antd-table-onchange-event-gives-a-previous-value#comment117114488_66240171

Comment: И да, забыл сказать, что я только как 2-3 месяца занимаюсь серьёзно с js & react. Это чей-то проект на работе, а я его допиливаю.